# Is the Union-Find (or Disjoint Set) data structure in STL?

Tags: c++, stl, disjoint-sets, union-find

I would have expected such a useful data structure to be included in the `C++ Standard Library` but I can't seem to find it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498833/implementing-disjoint-sets-union-find-in-c

Comment: I don't think it's *widely* useful enough for it to be worth the trouble to standardise, implement, and maintain. (My gut feeling is that the percentage of C++ projects that would benefit from it is closer to zero than to one.)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not, but there is one in boost: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/disjoint_sets/disjoint_sets.html, so if you want an off-the-shelf implementation I'd recommend this.

Comment: There's no documentation and it is super-generic in typical Boost style, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4136058/265521) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4136546/265521) give an idea how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

No. I written a simple implementation. It's very extensible.

```cpp
struct DisjointSet {
    vector<int> parent;
    vector<int> size;

    DisjointSet(int maxSize) {
        parent.resize(maxSize);
        size.resize(maxSize);
        for (int i = 0; i < maxSize; i++) {
            parent[i] = i;
            size[i] = 1;
        }
    }

    int find_set(int v) {
        if (v == parent[v])
            return v;
        return parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
    }

    void union_set(int a, int b) {
        a = find_set(a);
        b = find_set(b);
        if (a != b) {
            if (size[a] < size[b])
                swap(a, b);
            parent[b] = a;
            size[a] += size[b];
        }
    }
};
```

And the usage as follows.

```cpp
void solve() {
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    DisjointSet S(n);  // Initializing with maximum Size
    S.union_set(1, 2);
    S.union_set(3, 7);
    int parent = S.find_set(1);  // root of 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The implementation of disjoint set using tree. There are two operations:

1. find_set(x): get representative of set which contains member x, here representative is the root node
2. union_set(x,y): union of two sets which contain members x and y

Tree representation is efficient than linked list representation with two heuristics:
-- "union by rank" and "path compression" --

union by rank: assign rank to each node. Rank is height of the node (number of edges in the longest simple path between the node and a descendant leaf)

path compression: during "find_set" operation, make parent of node as root

(Ref: Introduction to Algorithms, 3rd Edition by CLRS)

The STL implementation is given below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct disjointSet{
    vector<int> parent, rank;
    disjointSet(int n){
        rank.assign(n, 0);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            parent.push_back(i);
    }

    int find_set(int v){
        if(parent[v]!=v)
            parent[v] = find_set(parent[v]);
        return parent[v];
    }

    void union_set(int x,int y){
        x = find_set(x);
        y = find_set(y);
        if (rank[x] > rank[y])
            parent[y] = x;
        else{
            parent[x] = y;
            if(rank[x]==rank[y])
                rank[y]++;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: Please read: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) Then (at least) update your answer to include the appropriate **Standard** header files.